# Is it possible to connect to an application using Component Services without a Windows domain environment?

Tags: windows, com+

Can you connect to an application using Component Services COM+ without a Windows domain environment?

Comment: Can you add which portion of component services you need access to?  Consider adding the `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService` ACE to the security permissions of this resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this in a long time, but I believe this is possible if you have:

1. Matching local user accounts (same username + password) on your local and remote systems
2. Administrator privileges, with that account, on the remote system

You might be able to get through with a 'net use \computername\ipc$' 
You could specify credentials in the net use command, if that helped.

Good luck!